# I have to create an interactive game where ChooseAxe is a boolean parameter but i dont understand whats going on an

Tags: java, parameters, boolean

```java
public static void ChooseWeapon( boolean ChooseAxe, boolean ChooseBat)
{
    System.out.print("Tommy: Okay Sarah, Pick a weapon off the table and lets go get the meds.\n" +
    "Your Options are:\nAxe(1) or Bat(2)\nEnter Value:");   

    String response = scan.nextLine();

    if (response.equals("1"))
    {
        ChooseAxe = true; 
        System.out.print("Tommy: Okay pick up the Axe and lets go");
        GetTheMeds();
    }
    else if(response.equals("2"))
    {
        ChooseBat = true;
        System.out.print("Tommy: Okay pick up the Axe and lets go");
        GetTheMeds();
    }
}
```

I have to create an interactive game where `ChooseAxe` is a boolean parameter but I don't understand whats going on. How do I pass the result onto another method? Because later on the game ask for the weapon the user chooses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Have a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but it'd probably be best if you stuck with Java naming conventions, e.g., methods and variables start with lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Class Variable outside the method to store the variables, you dont need the parametres in the method.

```
    static boolean axe, bat;
    public static void ChooseWeapon()
    {
// Ask the user to make a choice for weapon
System.out.print("Tommy: Okay Sarah, Pick a weapon off the table and lets go get the meds.\n" +
"Your Options are:\nAxe(1) or Bat(2)\nEnter Value:");   

//Reads users reponse and chooses output
String response = scan.nextLine();

//Decisions... decisions
if (response.equals("1"))
{
    axe = true; 
    bat = false;
    System.out.print("Tommy: Okay pick up the Axe and lets go");
    GetTheMeds();
}
else if(response.equals("2"))
{
    bat = true;
    axe = false;
    System.out.print("Tommy: Okay pick up the Axe and lets go");
    GetTheMeds();
}
}//end method ChooseWeapon()
```

Then user get methods to get the values, just call them from the other method

```
public static boolean getAxe(){
return axe;
}
public static boolean getBat(){
return bat;
}
```